# Need input on DB design approach: indexing words per text file, remembering position

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I've got the following design problem:

Say I have 1 million of plain text files approximately 10KB in size. My goal is to devise a way to store an index of all words, such that I can link each word to a particular text file and word's location within said file.

Example:

```
Text file X contents: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
                       0   1     2     3   4     5    6   7    8

Text file Y contents: "Now is the time for all good men"
                       0   1  2   3    4   5   6    7
```

I want to store roughly the following:

```
the   => {X,0}, {X,6}, {Y,2}
quick => {X,1}
is    => {Y,1}
.... and so on
```

Obviously I'm not indexing plain-text file in reality, my indexer is a multithreaded C# application that distills input to terms "file", "word", "position". I can't create a typical lookup table set because number of rows will easily grow beyond 2 billion.

My idea at first was to store pairs {message,position} in a text blob primary-keyed with word itself. With this solution, however, I am afraid that there will be a huge contention when all my threads will try to update a row for "the" with new pairs of {message,position}.

I am locked to my environment, SQL Server Express 2012, so let's work with what we have.
I can do anything with the database itself, in fact my app creates the database as part of normal workflow, hence I can deploy CLR stored procs if needed.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you really want position solely in terms of word order within a file a not as a (Unicode) character offset?  The offset would let you easily extract a phrase complete with the original case and punctuation.  It would help to know what kinds of queries you plan to do against the data in order to suggest an appropriate design.

Comment: I'm essentially implementing a pico-lucene :) I will perform search queries like: find me word "internet" within 5 words of "explorer"

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but your problem is... too many rows per table? Too many fields for record? Or too many rows in absolute? I do not know the limits of SQL Server Express...

Comment: You might be hitting the database size limit in SQL Express (10 GB) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx - you will need to consider Standard edition if you need more storage.

Comment: @Ed Harper: AFAIK this was tested on a standard edition

Comment: @p.marino: Too many rows per table

Comment: @YuriyGettya - when you say "too many rows", were you using an `int IDENTITY` primary key? If so, have you tried switching the PK to `bigint`. In any case, could you update the question with the error messages generated?

Comment: @EdHarper: I am using bigint for all PK's. However this is not the problem that people working on a similar project experienced before. The actual problem is that a simple lookup table with two columns (fileId, wordId) get populated astonishingly fast. I do not have information about exact problems experienced, what I do know is that number of rows would be in billions, which is unacceptable.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements: you want something which is fast (avoiding lock contention) and takes as little space as possible (limitation of your chosen DB). If you optimize for locking you create too many rows, if you optimize for size (and I doubt you may do better than a bitarray for size) you get lock contention...

Comment: That's why I'm asking this question :) It doesn't have to be super-fast, just lock contention would be REALLY bad with an 8-core CPU for instance, as well as running out of space in the table ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to throw something out, create a table with one row per file.  Use an `xml` column to store the word occurrences for the file.

A second table is your word list.  Denormalize by adding a cross reference table that lets you quickly locate which files contain which words.

Now you can throw that out.

Comment: well, quantity of my "files" can easily be on the order of 10's of millions. Denormalized lookup will blow up row count to unmanageable numbers. In fact SQL server 2008 cr@pped out at 2.5 billion rows in the lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this... create an association table with word/file-id. Every record will have the two ids plus a string made entirely of 0 and 1.

So given your example:

```
Text file X contents: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
                       0   1     2     3   4     5    6   7    8

Text file Y contents: "Now is the time for all good men"
                       0   1  2   3    4   5   6    7
```

You will get:

```
WordId | FileId | Position
the    | X      | 100001
the    | Y      | 001
quick  | X      | 01
is     | Y      | 01
....
```

(note that the position could be also stored as an actual bitmask to save space, but I am not sure if this will not prove problematic when using or updating the values)

This trick is based on something called "Rushmore Indexing", btw.

Now to see the distance between "the" and "quick" in file "X" you have to read both rows and count the number of zeroes between instances of "is" and instances of "the".
Note that you can also add extra info like "number of occurrences of word in the file to make the actual distance match easier:

```
WordId | FileId | Position |Occ
the    | X      | 100001   | 2
the    | Y      | 000001   | 1 
quick  | X      | 01       | 1
is     | Y      | 01       | 1
....
```

In this case you immediately know that "the" appears twice in file X, while "quick" will appear only once. This may get handy to structure the distance counting routine.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this won't scale well for two reasons: (1) with the parallelism I have contention of updating will move to "Occ" and Position and (2) having a single row per combination of word/file would blow up the row count of this table. There's roughly 400K actively used words in English language x 2 million files = too much.

Comment: Do you expect to have all 400000 words in all the 2 millions files? you mentioned the files are on average 10k of text, so I sincerely doubt that this will be the case...  note that the wordid-fileid row will be created *only* if a given word is present at least once in a given file...

Comment: @pmarino: take a look at my comment to Ed Harper above please.

Comment: Yuriy, I don't understand if you are saying that "someone else" managed to do this already in SQL Server Express and you are trying to replicate the feat. If this is *not* the case, maybe you have to just realize that this cannot be done with the specified product.

Comment: It was almost done several years ago with a commercial SQL server distribution. They ran into problems with exploding row count in the lookup table: { FileId, WordId }.

Comment: then why do you expect that now it's doable with a non-commercial SQL product?

Comment: Because I am looking for an alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

A DB is overkill for what you are doing. Have you considered using something like [NoSQL](http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=nosql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) or something even lighter?
And you should probably make some worker threads that updates the index in background, instead
of having a lot of threads updating it. That'll reduce contention...

Comment: This is only a small part of a larger project with a certain workflow and I need DB for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your plain text documents consist only of indexed words (i.e. there are no unindexed parts such as punctuations, or you are content to include the punctuations in the index), perhaps the following idea would be worth a try:

[image]

As you can see, there is no separate "document" content. The "document" and the "index" are one and the same and the document can be reconstructed on the fly by traversing DOCUMENT_WORD in proper ORDER and looking up the WORD_TEXT from the WORD.

This model has couple of nice properties:

- Data is not duplicated between documents and index, saving space.
- Same word can be shared by many documents - word text will be stored only once, which saves space. This is actually a form of dictionary *compression*.
- DOCUMENT_WORD is a good candidate for [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), so all words of the same document are stored physically close, which should minimize the I/O during document reconstruction.
- With a little JOINing, you can query in both directions, either: "get the word on (or near) the given position", or: "get the positions of the given word".

BTW, if you ever decide to switch to Oracle, you can use leading-edge index compression in combination with clustering on DOCUMENT_WORD, to eliminate the repetition of DOCUMENT_ID and save even more space. You might be able to use SQL Server's [page compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464) to similar effect.

Comment: I see a couple problems with this. You cannot really "reconstruct" the original document by assembling words. Not only for the punctuation, as you mention, but what about upper/lower cases? "I am the One, Human" is quite the different from "I am the one you are looking for" - not to mention line breaks, tabs, spacing - also, most indexing systems use stopword lists to skip common words like "the" or "a" which are useless in a search.

Comment: @p.marino Upper/lower case differences could be simply declared separate "words". There are usually only 2 case variations of a single word anyway. "Unsearchable" pieces of text could be marked with appropriate flag(s), etc... The word "word" should be taken very generally in this model.

Comment: I don't care about punctuation and stop words, so that is an interesting approach. I apologize that my examples led you to believe that I DO care about all words. This is not the case. Stop words "the", "is", "as", "and" etc, will be omitted by the indexer

Comment: @branko - your approach has merit, but as you see below it is not possible not to store the original text somewhere, because the indexed words are a subset of the whole text.

Comment: Looking at the proposed solution again, it still has the dreaded lookup table { FileId, WordId }, that I am trying to get rid of by consolidating some data into a single row.

Comment: @Yuriy, the moment you get rid of the lookup you start complaining about the contention...

Comment: :) I know. I am looking for a way to *reduce* contention while avoiding standard lookup table that is known to not give adequate results

Comment: @YuriyGettya Either you'll pay the storage price (by storing WORD_TEXT directly in DOCUMENT_WORD), or the performance price (for the lookup table). Take your pick. But don't take it before you perform **measurements** on realistic amounts of data!

Comment: @p.marino You said: _"it is not possible not to store the original text somewhere, because the indexed words are a subset of the whole text."_ Let us index **everything** then, and just mark the unsearchable "words" accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Comments screw up code formatting, so here it goes:

I am marking post above as an answer since this is the core of the solution that I devised. I store positions and word id's in an xml column, unique words are normalized into a separate lookup table. When searching I do an XPath query similar to this:

```
m.WordIndex.query('
    let $dummy := 0
    return
        <word_list>
        {
            for $w in /wi/w
                where $w/@wid=1
                return <word wid="1" pos="{data($w/p)}"/>
        }
        </word_list>
    ') as WordPosition
```